# Can a vararg parameter be of type <? super Object>?

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I'm writing a method to check if parameters of my methods are null, and I was just opened up to the idea of varargs, so I wrote a cool catch-all method:

```
private <T> void checksIfNull(T... t) throws NullPointerException {
    for (T myT : t) {
        if ( myT == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Attempted to pass a null object");
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting greedy. If I need to check a `String`, `List`, and `int`, all in one meeting, it means I have to write this in the calling method:

```
checksIfNull(myString);
checksIfNull(myList);
checksIfNull(myInt);
```

I'm wondering if there's a way that I would only every have to call the null-checking method once using  combined with a generic parameter. I feel there might be - but I may have the syntax wrong. I've tried some combinations of the following but it never quite works out:

```
private <T> void checksIfNull(T<? super Object>... t) throws NullPointerException {
    for (T myT : t) {
        if ( myT == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Attempted to pass a null object");
        }
    }
}
```

My right hand parameter of `T<? super Object>... t` is telling me "Type T does not have type parameters.

Comment: Generics don't work with primitive types like `int`

Comment: Why not just use `Object` as the type, and not worry about generics?

Comment: What's the point in using a generic here? You neither care or use the generic type `T`. Just use `Object...` and be fine with that.

Comment: *facepalm* Of Course. Thanks all.

Comment: Haha, no worries :) Often times the best questions are the ones where there is just a small disconnect in solving the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics aren't adding any value here. Having `T... t` implies there's some commonality among the types of the parameters, something you're trying to avoid. You can simply use `Object...`.

```
private void checksIfNull(Object... values) throws NullPointerException {
    for (Object value: values) {
        if (value == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Attempted to pass a null object");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend also renaming the method to `requireNonNull(Object...values)` . This convention agrees with similar, single-parameter static methods provided by the `Objects` class.

Comment: I've seen that method elsewhere. Would I be able to just @override it?

Comment: @NateH06 Only if you inherit from the class which contains that method and that method is neither static or private.

Comment: No, it's a static method.

Comment: Got it, I can just call `Object.requireNonNull(String/Integer/etc.)` directly. Thanks!